# Errors in rvest when trying to scrape text

Tags: dataframe, html-table, rvest

I'm trying to get some discography data from this website "https://www.discogs.com/artist/272142-Robert-Johnson?filter_anv=0&subtype=Writing-Arrangement&type=Credits&layout=med"

I'm using this code and the rvest package:

```
page <- read_html("https://www.discogs.com/artist/272142-Robert-Johnson?
filter_anv=0&subtype=Writing-Arrangement&type=Credits")

page %>% html_node(".year , #m26093 .icon-caret-down, .skittles, #m820658 
img, .label, .title") %>% 
html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

I obtained the html nodes using the selector gadget.  I've been getting several error messages no matter how I arrange the code (i.e., piping, nesting).

These are the messages:

1) Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "character"

2) Error: html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to scrape? The node you describe is an `img` tag, not a `table`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm trying to scrape the table that has information about bands that have released records with songs written by Robert Johnson.  The table has images in it, but I'm not specifically targeting them. I'm using this currently and still getting errors.

     page %>% html_node(".year , .label, .title") %>% html_text() %>%   
    html_table()

Comment: what's wrong with `page %>% html_node('table') %>% html_table`?

Comment: Hi, that will work just fine, but it only provides the first 25 rows out of 500.  I haven't been able to make it past this hangup.

Comment: Change the URL: https://www.discogs.com/artist/272142-Robert-Johnson?sort=year%2Casc&limit=500&filter_anv=0&subtype=Writing-Arrangement&type=Credits&layout=med&page=1

Comment: That's it!! how did you figure out what was wrong if I might ask? Thanks!

Comment: I looked at the page and saw the option "Show 25" and changed it to "Show 500" and saw the URL changed.

Comment: Wow, I thought it was probably something very simple.  Thank you.